# Okay with newline before semi-colon?

Tags: c, ubuntu-16.04

I'm new to C programming. I write a Basic C code
like

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
    int t = 
5
;
    printf("%d\n",t
);
}
```

Is it going to produce a error?

Well, my questing is like

```
int x = 9;
```

and

```
int x = //Finish this instruction in 3 lines instead of one!
9
;
```

Both are correct? Can i end a instruction in by using multiple line

Comment: Change `main()` to `int main()` to fix the warning.

Comment: Depends on your definition of 'correct'.  I would argue the code is not correct just because of the indentation!

Comment: Thanks, But i'm not concern about the warning. Just asking that can i End a statement/instructions in the multiple Line or not.

Comment: @Bechitra Yes, and that fact can be useful for formatting code, just make sure you are actually improving it and not obfuscating it :)

Comment: Yes, you can write code like this, but it's unusual and IMO it doesn't make the code more readable. You can also put your whole code on a single line, it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Re-written answer after question has been clarified.

Yes, the position of the semi-colon doesn't matter. Whitespace (space, newline, tab) generally don't matter in C. It's not a line-oriented language, where source code must be rigidly structured into lines. There are lines, but they're not very important. Almost always, a newline can be changed into a space (or even removed) without changing the meaning of the code.

These are all equivalent:

```
int x = 1;

int y=1;

int z=1          ;

int
w
=
1
;
```

You should check out some [Obfuscated C entries](http://www.ioccc.org/) for how this can be used to creative effect.

Answer (score 1):

In olden K&R days before the ANSI C standard, the default type for any function or variable was `int` so you could (and people frequently did) omit the type specifier in a declaration if the type was meant to be `int`. This was idiomatic, particularly in the case of the `main()` function (Even "The C Programming Language second edition" used the convention even though it was allegedly based on ANSI C). There was also no `void` type so you could not specify that a function returned nothing. Functions always returned something, even if it was a garbage value.

Beginning with (I think) C99, it was decided that defaulting the type to `int` was a really bad idea and so it is technically not allowed. However, for backward compatibility, compilers just emit a warning when they come across it.

You can silence the warning with either

```
int main(void)
```

or

```
int main(int argc, char*argv[])
```

Those are the two "official" portable definitions in C11.

While you are at it, although you do not need to specify a `return` statement in `main`, it's good practice to do so. Add

```
return 0;
```

to the end of the `main` function.

**EDIT**

The question has changed while I was writing the answer.

As regards splitting statements across lines like in the question. There is no problem with doing this as far as the compiler is concerned. White space (space, tab, newline, form feed) is not significant in C. The only place where you need it is where it would make two tokens run in to one e.g. `intmain` obviously wouldn't work and everywhere one white space is legal so is any amount of white space.

Also comments can appear pretty much anywhere you can put white space. e.g.

```
int/* blah */foo = 5;
```

Is legal

Answer (score -1):

in C your do function declaration like that :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
```

int -> return type of the function. This function will return an interger

main -> function's name (here the main function of your programm)

(int argc, char **argv) -> the paranthesis, showing it's a function, and the parameters of the function; what it takes as input.

just few advices don't write semicolon on a new line it's a bad practice

Comment: @anatolyg this was edited after i posted then no reason to down vote ...